# Python number format changing after styling

Tags: python, css, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe that resembles the following:

| Name | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3,580,093,709.00 |
| B | 5,656,745,317.00 |

Which I am then applying some styling using CSS, however when I do this the Amount values become scientific formatted so `3.58009e+09` and `5.39538e+07`.

| Name | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3.58009e+09 |
| B | 5.65674e+07 |

How can I stop this from happening?

```
d = {'Name': ['A', 'B'], 'Amount': [3580093709.00, 5656745317.00]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df= df.style
df
```

Comment: Show us how you do the styling part.

Comment: The issue seems to be happening as soon as use df.style

Comment: example code added

Comment: df.style.format({'Amount': '{:,.2f}'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing how you are styling the columns but, to set it as a float with two decimals, you should add the following to your styler, based on the first line of Pandas documentation (they write it for something):

```
df = df.style.format(formatter={('Amount'): "{:.2f}"})
```

Here is the link for more information:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html